# How can I upload to the root media library folder with strapi when uploading with the API?

Tags: strapi, cloudinary

I am trying to upload images to the root media library folder in strapi using the cloudinary provider. In the documentation it states that:

> Files uploaded through the REST or GraphQL API are located in the automatically created "API Uploads" folder.

How can I upload them to the root folder or is it not possible?

I tried looking at the documentation and I cannot find anything helpful. I also looked at the documentation for the cloudinary provider, however, I only find options to add configuration on the cloudinary end.

I am using strapi version 4.5.6

Answer (score 0):

If you upload to Cloudinary without specifying a path or a folder (folder: "your_folder"), the media asset will be placed in the root folder.

Comment: I was trying to upload to the root folder in the strapi media library. The reason why I did this was because the image field in the api response did not include the image data. I then solved the issue by extending the core controller for the findOne action, adding population for the response data. Thanks for taking the time to help! Much appreciated.